# Rubyスクリプトで変換したPDFのメタデータが認識されません

Tags: ruby, pdf

OCR未適用のPDFを、ScanSnap iX500付属ソフト「検索可能なPDFに変換」で変換しようとしていますが、変換対象として認識されません。

[記事を参考](http://kenkiti.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20120424/p1)に、Rubyのスクリプトでメタデータの「creatortool」を「PFU ScanSnap Organizer 4.1.41 #S1500」に変換しましたが、下記イメージのように「状態：対象外」となります。どうすれば変換できるようになるでしょうか。

> メタデータ変換スクリプト
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'mini_exiftool'
>
> # 以下の2行は、ご自身の環境にあわせて書き換えてください。
> creatortool = "PFU ScanSnap Organizer 4.1.41 #S1500"
> path_to_pdf = "/Users/kenkiti/Dropbox/スキャン文書/**/*.pdf" 
>
> Dir.glob(path_to_pdf) do |f|
>   target = MiniExiftool.new(f)
>   if target['CreatorTool'] != creatortool 
>     target['CreatorTool'] = creatortool
>     target.save
>     puts "#{f} => #{target['CreatorTool']}" 
>   end
> end
> ```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スクリプトが問題なく実行できたのか気になります。スクリプトの実行結果を念のため載せてください。また、引用元のスクリプトとあなたの環境が同一なのでしょうか。お持ちの ScanSnap が S1500 なのか、Organizer のバージョンが 4.1.41 なのか、そこも気になります。

Comment: スクリプトは問題なく完了しました。　　
「exiftool」のバージョンは,9.82。   
「検索可能なPDFに変換.app」は、6.0.10.1007。
「ScanSnap Manager」は、6.0.10.1023。    
「ScanSnap Organizer」はmacのため入っておりません。
また、所有しているScanSnapは「ScanSnap iX500」になります。そのため、creatortoolを「creatortool = "PFU ScanSnap Manager 6.0.10.1023"」など試してみてみましたが、「検索可能なPDFに変換.app」で対象外と認識されてしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

手元に ScanSnap が無いので当方で確認できませんが、 ScanSnap でスキャンしたファイルの項目を確認すれば `creatortool` に設定する項目名が分かるのではないでしょうか。
以下で項目名を確認してみてください。

```
require 'mini_exiftool'

# ScanSnapでスキャンしたファイルのパスを設定してください
path_to_pdf = "/Users/**/*.pdf" 

Dir.glob(path_to_pdf) do |f|
  target = MiniExiftool.new(f)
  puts target['CreatorTool']
end
```

その項目名を元のスクリプトの `creatortool` に設定してください。

もしもこれで動作しないのであれば、「検索可能なPDFに変換」で変換できる pdf ファイルの条件が元記事の当時とは異なっているのでしょう。ご自身で条件を探ってみてください。

Comment: ヒント：元スクリプトを `target['CreatorTool']` じゃなく `target['creator']` にすると幸せになれるかも。

Comment: target['creator']にしたら、
「ScanSnap Manager #iX500」と出力されました。また、「検索可能なPDFに変換.app」では、対象外とならず変換処理が終了(一見正常終了しているように見えます。)しましたが、中身は検索可能なものではありませんでした。